# How do I pass a function pointer to a javascript function using GWT's JSNI?

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I've used the JSNI before but I've never had to pass a function pointer as a parameter using it and I'm not sure how to do this.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to pass a [JavaScriptObject](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject.html) that represents a JavaScript function object. I don't think you can do anything with Java functions, though. So for example you could:

```
final native JavaScriptObjet myFuncCreator() /*-{
    return function (x, y) { return y - x; };
}-*/

final native int myFuncUser(JavaScriptObject funcObj, int a, int b) /*-{
    return funcObj(a,b);
}-*/
```

Admittedly, I didn't try this code but I believe it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Along the same lines as sinelaw's answer, here's a way to get a callback.

```
static final native JavaScriptObject createFunction(final Runnable runnable)
/*-{
    return function() {
        runnable.@java.lang.Runnable::run()();
    }
}-*/

static final void registerOnClickCallback(Element element, final Runnable runnable) {
    JavaScriptObject callback = createFunction(runnable);
    _registerOnClickCallback(element, callback);
}

static final native void _registerOnClickCallback(Element element, JavaScriptObject callback)
/*-{
    element.onclick = callback;
}-*/
```

Hope this helps!

- [GWT Coding Basics JNSI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)
- [JNI Types and Data Structures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html)